# On Ubuntu, bash script always returns 0 even when set -o errexit is set

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a script called `test.sh` on a brand new Ubuntu 14.04.2 which does this:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -o errexit

# Start by building the box
docker build -t dcyclebox-test .

# Test nginx
docker run dcyclebox-test bash -c 'nginx -v' && echo '[test] nginx works'

echo '[status] end of test script'
```

The nginx command does not exist, so I expect the fact that I set `set -o errexit` at the beginning of the script to make the entire script return a non-zero error code, but the script always returns 0:

```
$ test.sh 
...
bash: nginx: command not found
[status] end of test script
$ echo $?
0
```

It seems that `set -o errexit` does nothing at all. The script will return a non-zero exit code as expected if I remove the last line, which says `echo '[status] end of test script'`:

```
$ test.sh 
...
bash: nginx: command not found
$ echo $?
127
```

But I want the script to fail if *any* of the lines fail, not only the last one. The only thing I can do for now is add `&&\` to the end of each line, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Start by building the box
docker build -t dcyclebox-test . &&\

# Test nginx
docker run dcyclebox-test bash -c 'nginx -v' && echo '[test] nginx works' &&\

echo '[status] end of test script'
```

Now, running the script will fail (which is good) if nginx is not present (notice I removed `set -o errexit` because it does not seem to do anything.)

```
$ test.sh 
...
bash: nginx: command not found
$ echo $?
127
```

So my question is what command can I add to the top of my script tell it to exit if any of the commands in it exit with a non-zero code?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the explicit line continuation after `&&`; a command cannot end with that operator, so the shell knows that it will continue on the following line.

Answer (score 5):

Since your shebang is `#!/bin/sh` and `sh` is symlinked to `dash` on Ubuntu, `dash`'s rules govern execution of your script.

With respect to `set -e` and its equivalent, `set -o errexit`, `man dash` states (emphasis mine):

> -e errexit        If not interactive, exit immediately **if any untested command fails.  The exit status of a command is considered to be explicitly
>                   tested if the command is used to control an if, elif, while, or until; or if the command is the left hand operand of an “&&” or
>                   “||” operator**.

Based on this definition, the LHS (left-hand side) of your command

```
docker run dcyclebox-test bash -c 'nginx -v' && echo '[test] nginx works'
```

*is* an explicitly tested command, and therefore automatic termination in case of failure of the LHS command does *not* kick in.

You can work around this by simply making `echo '[test] nginx works` a *separate* command (which you can obviously also place on a new line):

```
docker run dcyclebox-test bash -c 'nginx -v'; echo '[test] nginx works'
```

Now, if `docker run dcyclebox-test bash -c 'nginx -v'` fails (returns a nonzero exit code), the script is terminated instantly (reporting that exit code).

Comment: @alberto56 You really do have to mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the man page:

Exit  immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command), a list, or a compound command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above),  exits with a non-zero status.  **The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the  command  list  immediately  following  a  while  or  until keyword, part of the test following the if or elif reserved words, *part of any command executed in a &&* or || list except the command following the *final &&*  or  ||, any  command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return value is being inverted with !.**  If a compound command other than a subshell returns a non-zero status because a command failed while -e was being  ignored,  the shell does not exit.  A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the shell exits.  This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment separately (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT above), and may cause sub‐ shells to exit before executing all the commands in the subshell.

Comment: You're quoting from the `bash` manual (without saying so), which doesn't apply here, because the script's shebang line specifies `sh`, which is `dash` on Ubuntu. As it so happens, what you quote also applies to `dash`, because, as `dash`, `bash` seems to follow the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25_03) here, by and large (truthfully, I didn't try to understand all the intricacies).

Comment: You're right. I'm on Fedora and wasn't aware of the dash/bash split on Debian/Ubuntu. Upvoting your answer.